# I cannot access files downloaded in Ubuntu and moved to NTFS partition in Windows

Tags: dual-boot, filesystem, windows-10

I downloaded some RAR files in my Ubuntu, then I copied them to my NTFS drive to access from Windows 10. But after logging into Windows I see the folder as having 0 Byte size and I could not open any folder that I created in Ubuntu.

Please let me know what I have to do.

Comment: How does the file look like in Ubuntu ?

Comment: This is due I believe to hibernation in windows (could be fast boot).